# How to make exported {gt} table (png) have non-bold text

Tags: r, gt

I'm finding that all the text in an exported gt table (png or PDF) is bold even if the RStudio version in the viewer has non bold.

I'm guessing this is due to the fact that much of the LaTeX formatting has not been implemented (HTML only), some links to this issue in GitHub are below.

As they work on implementing formatting that applies to LaTeX as well as HTML, any suggestions on an approach to get non-bold text?

UPDATE Nov 11, 2021: I tested this on a brand-new computer and the bold was not there. Hmm. Perhaps it's a font issue?

Zev

```r
gt::exibble %>%
  gt::gt(
    rowname_col = "row",
    groupname_col = "group"
  ) %>% 
  gt::tab_style(
    style = gt::cell_text(weight = "normal"),
    locations = gt::cells_body()
  ) %>% 
  gt::tab_style(
    style = gt::cell_text(weight = "bold"),
    locations = gt::cells_column_labels()
  ) %>% 
  gt::gtsave("~/junk/exibble.png")
```

In the RStudio viewer (before gtsave):

[image]

The PNG from export

[image]

- https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/619
- https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/119
- https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/634
- https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/819

Comment: I haven't this problem with your code

Comment: I can't replicate the issue when exporting to .png either

Comment: it is asking me to `webshot::install_phantomjs()`. Maybe try that to update some things?

Comment: I think what is happening is a lack of the font used.. somewhere.. because it is defaulting to another font entirely.

Comment: @manro (and Matt) are you saying that when you run this code, you're not seeing bold?

Comment: @Mossa when you run the code after installing phantomjs are you seeing bold? What makes you say it's a lack of the font used? Are you seeing something that suggests this?

Comment: @ZRoss no, all right

Comment: It works fine for me, no bold. I'm throwing the font thing out there, because I'm staring at your image, and I'm thinking the font don't match.

Comment: You could try my huxtable package: it's quite good for pdfs.

Comment: @dash2 I'll try today your package. Which are main pros of your library in relation to others?